# Problems after updating angular Project from 14 to 15

Tags: angular

My app won't work and I don't know what to do.

I searched but didn't found something

```html
./src/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Only 0 arguments allowed, but 1 was passed.
  ┌──> src/material.theme.scss
147│ @include mat-core($fontConfig);
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ invocation
  ╵
  ┌──> node_modules/@angular/material/core/_core.scss
8 │ @mixin core() {
  │        ━━━━━━ declaration
  ╵
  src/material.theme.scss 147:1  core()
  src/material.theme.scss 147:1  @import
  src/styles.scss 5:9            root stylesheet
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete node_modules and package-lock. and then run npm i

Comment: Now I get another Error. I put a picture. Look at the second Picture

Comment: you have errors in your sass files. One way to see it is to remove the offedning sass file, second post your sass file so that we can see

Comment: I got the same error like the first picture. I tried the same method again but now it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Do a npm cache clean --force. After that delete your node_modules folder then do a npm install

Comment: didint work for me

Comment: alright can your try npm install --save-dev webpack

Comment: didnt work either